# Limit of n times f applied to a function depending on n.

Tags: limits

I am trying to find, under what assumptions for $f:A\times B\to B$ and $g:\mathbb N\to A$, we have

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f^n(g(n),b) = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f^n\left(\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}g(m),b\right)$$
where $f^n(a,b) = f(a,f^{n-1}(a,b))$.

Is it enough to ask for $f$ to be a continuous function and the limit of $g$ to exists?

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely not enough. For example, consider the functions $f\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R},\ g\colon \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(m) = 2^{1/m}$, $f(a,b) = ab$. Then it's clear that $f^n(a,b) = a^nb$. Using this, we compute $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f^n(g(n),b) = 2b$$ while on the other hand $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f^n(\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}g(m), b) = 1^nb = b$$.

This is not rare, and it's unlikely you could impose any reasonable set of conditions on $f$ and $g$ to make this identity hold.

Comment: Thank you very much for the counterexample.
Now I am trying with more properties of my particular f. In particular, I think that I can define f^n as a sequence of functions, and prove that this is a Cauchy sequence. Then, use some properties there.